# Detecting if a Face is Upside down with Dlib.Net(FaceRecognition.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, face-detection, dlib

Basically i'm trying to check if a face is upside down in an image using this library https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/FaceRecognitionDotNet.
Take example of the image below

[image]

This is an image that is successfully detected using the FaceRecognition.Net library.The image is upside down.I have marked all face landmarks in the image with a blue ellipses.

This is the approach i follow

```
 // Finding faceparts
var faceparts = dparameters._FaceRecognition.FaceLandmark(dparameters.FCImage);

// Drawing Ellipses over all points got from faceparts

foreach(var facepart in faceparts) {
  foreach(var mypoint in facepart.Values) {
    foreach(var x in mypoint) {
      tempg.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, x.Point.X, x.Point.Y, 2, 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Now i'm checking if the image is rotated by comparing maximum Y coordinates of the lip and eyepoints

```
var temp = faceparts.FirstOrDefault();
IEnumerable < FacePoint > lippoints;
temp.TryGetValue(FacePart.BottomLip, out lippoints);

IEnumerable < FacePoint > eyepoints;
temp.TryGetValue(FacePart.LeftEye, out eyepoints);

var lippoint = lippoints.Max(r => r.Point.Y);
var topeyepoint = eyepoints.Max(r => r.Point.Y);
if (lippoint > topeyepoint) {
  bool isinverted = true;
} else {
  bool isinverted = false;
}
```

The issue is that even when the image is not upside down, the eyecoordinate is less than the face coordinate.This is because a false face is detected as outlined in the image.How to get over this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this library does not provide a confidence ratio for the results. Otherwise, I would suggest to try both the input and its flipped copy and take the one with higher confidence before doing the "eye over mouth" check.

So maybe what could help is:

- using the CNN model, in the original library it is called by

```py
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, number_of_times_to_upsample=0, model="cnn")
```

in the C# port it should be

```cs
_FaceRecognition.FaceLocations(image, 0, Model.Cnn)
```

That should give you a more accurate face bounding box which you can then compare with the bounding box of the landmarks. If you do the same for a flipped copy of the image, you can "emulate" the confidence I mentioned earlier and assume the orientation where the boxes match better. Then you can identify the orientation by the "eyes over mouth" test.

- as far as I noticed the library does not provide pre-trained data, so in order to use the `Cnn` model you need to train it by yourself. Selection of the dataset for training is of course very important. If you already performed the training, more/better training data might improve the accuracy.

Comment: I have tried the `CNN` Model.But using this model crashes the library.Did you try it out ?

Comment: No I didn't, sorry that I can't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of [@Isolin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605379/isolin)'s suggested approach

> try both the input and its flipped copy and take the one with higher confidence

might look like below. I'm using the library [FaceAiSharp](https://github.com/georg-jung/FaceAiSharp/) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FaceAiSharp.Bundle/)) instead of FaceRecognitionDotNet, because it provides the required confidence values. Note that this approach doesn't handle some cases that might be interesting in production, such as "What if there is no face (detected) at all?".

```bash
dotnet new console
dotnet add package FaceAiSharp.Bundle
dotnet add package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime
```

`Program.cs`:

```cs
using FaceAiSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

bool IsUpsideDown(Image<Rgb24> img)
{
    var imgFlip = img.Clone(x => x.Flip(FlipMode.Vertical));

    var det = FaceAiSharpBundleFactory.CreateFaceDetector();
    var faces = det.DetectFaces(img);
    var facesFlip = det.DetectFaces(imgFlip);
    FaceDetectorResult? face = faces.Count > 0 ? faces.MaxBy(x => x.Confidence) : null;
    FaceDetectorResult? faceFlip = facesFlip.Count > 0 ? facesFlip.MaxBy(x => x.Confidence) : null;

    if (!faceFlip.HasValue)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!face.HasValue)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return (face.Value.Confidence < faceFlip.Value.Confidence);
}

var img1 = Image.Load<Rgb24>(@"face.jpg");

if (IsUpsideDown(img1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upside-down");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Normal");
}
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of FaceAiSharp. It's MIT-licensed. Don't hesitate to open an [issue](https://github.com/georg-jung/FaceAiSharp/) if something doesn't work for you or could be improved.

Comment: This comment is more related to ImageSharp than FaceAiSharp, however if you get a weird result, try to check orientation from Exif Data (image.Metadata?.ExifProfile?.GetValue(ExifTag.Orientation); value other than 1 -> you need to (un)rotate/(un)flip it -> RotateMode.None, FlipMode.None).